# preferences.xml and extending DialogPreference

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences

I'm trying to extend the *DialogPreference* so I can have a *NumberPicker* for one of my
preferences. I've been reading:

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom
```

But I'm hitting an *'Error inflating NumberPickerReference'* message. I think I know
why, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

My *preferences.xml* looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_alertsEnabled"
        android:title="@string/alert_enable"
        android:summary="@string/alert_enable_desc"
        android:defaultValue="true" />

    <NumberPickerPreference 
        android:key="perf_Timer" 
        android:title="@string/timer" 
        android:negativeButtonText="@android:string/cancel" 
        android:dialogTitle="@string/timer" 
        android:summary="@string/timer_desc" 
        android:dialogMessage="@string/timer_desc" 
        android:positiveButtonText="@android:string/ok"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And in my projects *src* folder I have *NumberPickerReference.java.* I think the thing I'm missing is how to tell Android where to find *NumberPickerReference class*.

When *preferences.xml* is read in, I'm guessing it goes looking for the *NumberPickerReference class*, but doesn't find it.

Do I need to specify where to find the *NumberPickerReference.class* ? If yes, how do I do this ?

BTW, the app runs fine if I remove the `<NumberPickerReferecnes>` item from *preferences.xml*

Comment: Turns out all I had to do was put the package name in front of NumberPickerPreference. In preferences.xml I made this one change <com.marlonez.myapp.NumberPickerPreference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the path to that preference:

```
com.your.package_name.and_path.NumberPickerPreference
```

E.g.

```
<com.example.myapp.preferences.NumberPickerPreference
    android:key="perf_Timer" 
    android:title="@string/timer" 
    android:negativeButtonText="@android:string/cancel" 
    android:dialogTitle="@string/timer" 
    android:summary="@string/timer_desc" 
    android:dialogMessage="@string/timer_desc" 
    android:positiveButtonText="@android:string/ok"/>
```